# Spring MVC - caching at application level

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, request, single-page-application

I'm using Spring MVC for single page application developed in AngularJS.

First request is to login service, after that I'm calling to services A,B and C
which produce the data that I need in the client to build the page.

In each one of those services A,B and C need to call some DAO - which bring data from database.
The DAO name is X.

Now, when the user navigate in the application he calls those services again and again,
and I don't won't to go the the DB each time.
I want to go to the DB only once (for that matther - dao 'X') when doing login and to save that data in some Cache.

My Solution was to save the data that arrive from X in MAP in some bean:

```
@Component
public class XUtility {


    private Map<String, List<String>> xcache = new ArrayList<String>();


     // this method is being called only after login
    public void initX_Cache(String key) {
         if (xcache.containsKey(key)) {
             xcache.remove(key);
         }
    }
    // this method is called many times from service A,B,C..
    public List<String> getX(String key) {

        List<String> values = xcache.get(key);
        if (values != null) {
            return values;
        }
        List<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();


        //daos = call the Database ... 

        for (DAOObeject dao : daos) {
            vals.add(dao.getKey());
        }
        xcache.put(key, vals); // save in cache the
        return vals;
    }


}
```

My Question is does this is the right solution ?
Cause it looks like bad design that the application save the data in memory that way..
Can any one suggest better solution?

Hope I'm being clear enough.
Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing infrastructure code with your business logic. These should be completely separated. The easiest approach would be to use the caching abstraction which spring provides. Depending on your version of spring refer appropriate spring cache examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache results from methods using the `@Cacheable` annotation. This is a neat mechanism to optimize without having to write a whole load of HashMap get(), put() logic.

To use it, you need a `CacheManager` to be defined and caching to be enabled. Here's a self-contained example using Java based configuration. More information in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

However, given your results are ultimately from DAOs, you should probably be using EH-cache, Terracotta etc as this can cache at the entity level which will allow entities to be re-used across your application

```
public class CacheTest {
    public static class Service {
        @Cacheable("horseCache")
        public List<String> getX(String key) {
            System.out.println("Called for " + key);
            return Arrays.asList(key + "...");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
            cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("horseCache")));
            return cacheManager;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Inline application context definition to support self-contained example
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(Service.class);
        GenericBeanDefinition configDefition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        configDefition.setBeanClass(Config.class);
        context.registerBeanDefinition("bean", beanDefinition);
        context.registerBeanDefinition("config", configDefition);
        context.refresh();

        // actual example
        Service bean = context.getBean(Service.class);
        System.out.println(bean.getX("foo"));
        System.out.println(bean.getX("bar"));
        System.out.println(bean.getX("foo")); // demonstrate 2nd call is cached
    }

}
```

Output

```
Called for foo
[foo...]
Called for bar
[bar...]
[foo...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Ehcache.
Check the [this](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/pagecaching) link which briefs about Webpage caching.
In your case, you can define something similar to this in web.xml which will be specific to login -

`<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SimplePageCachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`

So, once your webpage is loaded post web service calls, it will be cached.